# Proof for the distribution of the increments of Gaussian and Poisson processes?

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

What is analytic proof for the fact that increments of a Gaussian process are again Gaussian?

How could I apply that to increments of Poisson process?

Maybe do I multiply characteristic function with complex variable 's' and inverse tansform?

Comment: Hint: $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ are _jointly_ Gaussian random variables. What does that suggest about the distribution of the increment $X(t_2)-X(t_1)$? Also, if $N(t)$ is the number of arrivals in $(0,t]$, then depending on which definition of Poisson process you are starting from, it is a given that the _increment_ $N(t_2)-N(t_1)$, which is the number of arrivals in $(t_1,t_2]$, is a Poisson random variable.